# How to find the user mobile number in Phonegap Android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am a beginner in Mobile development, working on `Phonegap` with `javascript` and `java`.

I have a scenario where "if user once register with the app, he will be default signin with the mobile number whenever he clicks on the app(same as `Whatsapp`)".

How to remember the mobile number for each device?.

Is there any plugin or any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a plugin to get the phone number

[Plugin](https://github.com/macdonst/TelephoneNumberPlugin)

I haven't tested it, just found. So you can get the number on device ready function and auto login the user.
Off topic: You can also use UUID to uniquely identify each device, rather than mobile number. You can use device plugin to get the unique number.

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/cordova_device_device.md.html#device.uuid